# How to declare functions with infix style in Idris

Tags: idris

The non infix example works:

```
myelem: (Eq a) => a -> List a -> Bool
myelem x []     = False
myelem x (y::ys) = x == y || (myelem x ys)
```

I've tried another permutation fo the following, where I remove
the backticks from the type declaration line, but either way it fails:

```
`myelem`: (Eq a) => a -> List a -> Bool
x `myelem` []     = False
x `myelem` (y::ys) = x == y || (x `myelem` ys)
```

This is using Idris 1.3.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only use the backticks on the usage site, not on the declaration site:

```
myelem: (Eq a) => a -> List a -> Bool 
myelem x []     = False
myelem x (y::ys) = x == y || (x `myelem` ys)
```

There is no way (I know of) to use infix syntax on the declaration site for the function you are just about to define.

*Edit:*
There is however a way to do what you want with infix functions in the bracket notation. The example is taken from the `Prelude`:

```
infixr 4 <$>
(<$>) : Functor f => (func : a -> b) -> f a -> f b
func <$> x = map func x
```